# How can I make Beautiful Soup show more of a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a program that shows the best deals on a certain website, and the website only loads more of their items if you scroll down to the bottom. When I use soup, it only gets the first set of items. Is there a way I can force the website to load more items? Thank you in advance!

Comment: That site's using JavaScript to load content asynchronously. The problem is not with how you parse the page, but how you load it (or *don't load it* to be exact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beautifulsoup only parses the HTML code you give it. It is unaware of any browser window or scrolling. Either the data is all there or not.

If the website reloads data later (e.g. after scrolling down) there is some JavaScript behind. Take a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which uses a webdriver (meaning an actual webbrowser) to access the website which also run all JavaScript code as usual.